# How $f(z)=z^n$ is continuous but its inverse doesn't map an open set to an open set?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, continuity

If a map $f: X \to Y$ is continuous then $f^{-1}(V)$ is open set in $X$ whenever $V$ is an open set in $Y$.

Consider $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ by $f(z)=z^n$. By this map the sector $r≤a$, $0≤θ<2π/n$ is mapped onto the disk $ρ ≤ a^n $; and by letting $a \to \infty$, $\mathbb{C}$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$ but $V=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : 0≤θ<2π/n\}$ is not an open set?

Is this contradicts the theorem stated in first line?

Comment: Your question is unclear (to me). Please edit so that you start by saying what open set $V$ in $Y$ has an inverse image that's not open.

Comment: I think you're conflating the pre-image of an open set and the "inverse."

Comment: Here $f^{-1}(V)=\{x\in X\mid f(x)\in V\}$, and the statement in the first line is not a theorem but a definition.

Comment: @drhab It is a theorem in most analysis courses, where the definition of continuity uses $\varepsilon-\delta$.

Comment: @lisyarus Thank you for informing me. I am a bit too "topology minded" I guess :-).

Comment: @drhab I was amazed when I first met the topological definition by its simplicity. Now it takes several minutes for me to figure out the classical $\varepsilon-\delta$ one!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $V \subset X$, then in general $V \neq f^{-1}(f(V))$. We can only say that $V \subset f^{-1}(f(V))$.

In your case, indeed, $V$ is not open, and $f(V) = \mathbb C$ is. But then $f^{-1}(f(V)) = f^{-1}(\mathbb C) = \mathbb C$ (because any complex number has at least one $n$-th root), which is open.

Comment: When we define the inverse function we restrict the domain of definition so that it is bijection. If so $f^{-1}(\mathbb{C})  = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : 0≤θ<2π/n\} \ne \mathbb{C}$

Comment: @Edi The $f^{-1}$ in the definition of continuity is not the inverse function, it is the preimage of a set: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Inverse_image